# How to create TypeScript types for a function that calls React setState with its arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This doesn't work because `Partial<IState>` returns a type that can have `undefined`s as values which are not acceptable by `setState`.

```
interface IState {
  bar: number
  baz: boolean
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bar: 123,
      baz: false,
    }
  }
  public render() {
    return null
  }
  public update(options: Partial<IState>) {
    this.setState(options)
  }
  public callUpdate() {
    this.update({ bar: 4 })
  }
}
```

The only solution i found is to add the current state to the setState as well:

```
this.setState({  ...this.state, ...options })
```

Is there any better way to do this?

*typescript version: 3.2.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use **Type Assertion**:

```
this.setState(options as IState)
```

Using `this.setState({  ...this.state, ...options })` is not recommended because you have to destructure the current state object, which is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that option is never undefined you can add an exclamation mark after the option that is the non null assertion operator.

```
  public update(options: Partial<IState>) {
    this.setState(options!)
  }
```

An I want to point out, that using `this.setState({  ...this.state, ...options })` can result data loss. Because this.state is not updated until the next render. If you want to use the current state you should use `this.setState(state => ({...state, ...options})` instead.